# Is there Win 10 UWP drivers? If has, how to package the UWP drivers and ship it to store?

Tags: uwp, installation, driver

we need to change our drivers to Win10 UWP package. however, currently I have no idea how to achieve it. I can only convert the legacy driver installer to "UWP" with DAC(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter), but it is dirty to install and then Run the App as administor while actually it's an installer. Then the App will install drivers to system. 
Also uninstall the UWP app will not remove the drivers package in system because there is no action we can put into the UWP uninstallation to invoke the actually uninstaller of the drivers.

Is there some other way to do so?
Can I write a native UWP app that can work as installer, and embed the inf files in it? 
Thanks

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 0):

No. Drivers are one of the examples of things you can't do with a UWP app as the APPX installer doesn't support them.
You also can't install drivers with a [Centennial](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop) app.

You'll have to install your driver with a different installer technology.